# Command Objects Java

Tags: java, swing

So I made a command Object which ticks whenever i clicked it. I used to have added to a button on my J panel but now I want to use a timer to tick the game automatically. I wanted to know how to use a command object without attaching it to a button.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;

public class BtickCommand extends AbstractAction{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
       gw.notifyObservers();
   }
}
```

That's my command object, I took out some of the calculations to save some space, but what it does is simply do some calculations then notifies my other panels to update. in my game class

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private Timer myTimer = new Timer(1000,this) ;

   private void play(){
       myTimer.start();
   }

   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {  
       gw.notifyObservers();
       System.out.println("It ticked");
   }
}
```

so in my game there in the action performed I don't know how to call to my command object without attaching it to a button. I need it run the command object from my action performed instead of a button.

Comment: Please show us some code demonstrating your latest attempt at this, and try to clarify/narrow down your question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't have your JFrame implement ActionListener. As a general rule, GUI's should not implement listener interfaces except for toy programs.
2. Instead pass an instance of your BtickCommand into your Swing Timer constructor. This class extends AbstractAction which means that it also implements the ActionListener interface and can be used anywhere that ActionListeners are used.

---

For example:

```
public class Game extends JFrame {
    private Timer myTimer = new Timer(1000, new BtickCommand()) ;

   private void play(){
       myTimer.start();
   }
}
```